# Save sparse pandas dataframe to different file types

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sparse-matrix

I'm working with IoT data from one source which send's tons of GB of sparse data from sensor readings. To make snapshots for analysis I try to export them to a small file and read it later as sparse panda dataframe to keep memory usage low.

With v1.0 of pandas things changes, a lot and I'm stuck :-(

Below my test workflow

1. Create some dummy sparse IoT data with different data types (int,
   float, string as a category, string, date)
2. convert them to panda dataframe (works fine)
3. save them (to find differences to sparse data) --> **Errors**
4. convert panda frame to sparse dataframe --> **Error** worked before v1.0
5. save them (to find differences to sparse data)
   --> **Errors**

Question:

- Please, who knows, what is wrong and how to fix it
- Is my approach of coming to a sparse dataframe correct in the new panda way?

Thanks a lot

First, create some sparse input data

```py
import datetime
import sys
import time
import random
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display, HTML

input_data = list()

# create the input for a sparse matrix with different dtypes
columns = list(map(chr, range(ord('F'), ord('Z') - 1)))
category = ['Category A', 'Category B', 'Category C']
random.seed('dsgsdf')
chunk_size = 100 * 1000  # for testing bigger or smaller data sets
for row in range(1 * chunk_size):
    r = dict()
    r['A'] = row
    if random.randint(0, 9) >= 3:
        r['B'] = str(datetime.datetime.now())  # make the datetime conversion a bit harder
    if random.randint(0, 9) >= 5:
        r['C'] = category[random.randint(0, len(category) - 1)]
    if random.randint(0, 9) >= 9:
        r['D'] = random.randint(0,1000)
    if random.randint(0, 9) >= 9:
        r['E'] = pd.util.testing.rands(4) # random string = no category
    r[columns[random.randint(0, len(columns) - 1)]] = float(random.randint(0, 1000)/2)
    input_data.append(r)
```

Convert to dense pandas dataframe

```py
dense_df = pd.DataFrame(input_data)
dense_df = dense_df.reindex(sorted(dense_df.columns), axis=1) # sort by column name
dense_df['B'] = pd.to_datetime(dense_df['B'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
dense_df['C'] = dense_df['C'].astype('category') # strings as category
dense_df = dense_df.convert_dtypes() # without this line the export works, but with the line lower memory usage
```

Save dense matrix to disk in different formats. This doesn't work, with line .convert_dtypes()

```py
dense_df.to_hdf("data/dense-data-c0.h5", key='my',complevel=0,mode='w',format='table')
dense_df.to_hdf("data/dense-data-c9.h5", key='my',complevel=9,mode='w',format='table')
dense_df.to_pickle("data/dense-data.pkl.zip")
dense_df.to_parquet("data/dense-data.parquet.gzip",compression="gzip",allow_truncated_timestamps=True)
dense_df.to_parquet("data/dense-data.parquet",allow_truncated_timestamps=True)
dense_df.to_pickle("data/dense-data.pkl")
dense_df.to_json("data/dense-data.json")
```

Convert to sparse matrix so save memory usage. This worked before pandas v1.0

```py
import numpy as np
start = time.time()
sparse_df = dense_df.copy()

# define some sparse dtypes
dtype_float = pd.SparseDtype('float')
dtype_int = pd.SparseDtype('int')
dtype_str = pd.SparseDtype('string')
dtype_datetime = pd.SparseDtype('datetime64')
sparse_df['B'] = sparse_df['B'].astype(dtype_datetime)
sparse_df['E'] = sparse_df['E'].astype(dtype_str)
sparse_df['D'] = sparse_df['D'].astype(dtype_int)
```

Save dense matrix to disk in different formats. This doesn't work

```py
sparse_df.to_hdf("data/sparse-data-c0.h5", key='my',complevel=0,mode='w',format='table')
sparse_df.to_hdf("data/sparse-data-c9.h5", key='my',complevel=9,mode='w',format='table')
sparse_df.to_pickle("data/sparse-data.pkl.zip")
sparse_df.to_parquet("data/sparse-data.parquet.gzip",compression="gzip",allow_truncated_timestamps=True)
sparse_df.to_parquet("data/sparse-data.parquet",allow_truncated_timestamps=True)
sparse_df.to_pickle("data/sparse-data.pkl")
sparse_df.to_json("data/sparse-data.json")
```

Comment: No one answered you huh? It seems like you were hitting some memory limit. Which may have well been caused by pandas implementing more copies of data in memory when you were doing operations like .convert_dtypes ets.
Did you find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 1):

1. **Skip using .convert_dtypes()**: Sometimes this method can cause headaches when saving to certain file formats like HDF5 and Parquet. So, try saving your DataFrame without converting the dtypes. You can manually convert columns to sparse dtypes before saving.
2. **Consider Dask for heavy lifting**: Dask is pretty handy for handling big datasets. It can split tasks across multiple cores or machines, which can be a real-time-saver. While it might not solve all your saving issues, it's great for prepping your data before saving.

here's a quick Dask trick you can try:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd 
# Pandas DataFrame to a Dask DataFrame
dask_df = dd.from_pandas(sparse_df, npartitions=...)
# Save Dask DataFrame
dask_df.to_parquet("data/sparse-data-dask.parquet", compression="gzip")
```

Give that a shot, and let me know if you need more help!